# OpenAI Gym suite_gym.load() Loading Error

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am trying to use:

```
suite_gym.load(env_name)
```

Registering it with this code:

```
from gym.envs.registration import register

register(
    id='env_name',
    entry_point='RL.envs:env',
    kwargs={'x': [], 'y': []},
)
```

gym.make() works perfectly so I know that the environment has successfully registered. However, when I call suite_gym.load() I get this value error:

```
The gym space None is currently not supported.
  In call to configurable 'wrap_env' (<function wrap_env at 0x7fb2f30b3550>)
  In call to configurable 'load' (<function load at 0x7fb2f30b35e0>)
```

I have tried so many different things and I'm really stuck. If you could help with this it would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it! So there was an issue with the self.observation_space variable in my environment class! So I fixed that and it no longer registers a None value. If you have this issue later on check to make sure you have a correct self.action_space() and self.observation_space()